# Detect Screen orientation while screen is off

Tags: android, orientation

I need to know the device orientation ,the problem is that when the screen is off the orientation is always in `Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`
how do i solve this issue ? I think that using gravity might be helpful ,but i wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Gravity won't help, a device on a flat table will read gravity in the z axis regardless of orientation.  Why do you need to know this when the screen is off?  Since you can't display anything (screen is off) what does it matter?

Comment: The lock screen only supports ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, it is not an issue.